# Is it possible to set-up a personal SVN Remote Repository which can be accessed through the Internet?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, repository

What I want to happen is have an SVN server on one computer, and have TortoiseSVN on other 3 computers, for example, and these 3 computers will be able to commit and checkout files from the SVN server, all of this via the Internet, and as much as possible, for free. Is this possible? Can you point me to some good tutorials? Thanks

So far, I am aware that such can be achieved via LAN.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at server configuration in the [SVN Red Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.serverconfig.choosing.html#svn.serverconfig.choosing.apache).

You have three choices - using svnserve, using svnserve over SSH, or Apache HTTP. Each has pros/cons, and these are discussed. Note also that you'll need to configure your firewall (port-forwarding etc.) as required.

From the Red Book article:

> If you're trying to set up the simplest possible server for your group, a vanilla svnserve installation is the easiest, fastest route. Note, however, that your repository data will be transmitted in the clear over the network. If your deployment is entirely within your company's LAN or VPN, this isn't an issue. **If the repository is exposed to the wide-open Internet, you might want to make sure that either the repository's contents aren't sensitive (e.g., it contains only open source code), or that you go the extra mile in configuring SASL to encrypt network communications.**

(my emphasis)

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is possible and not difficult to set-up!

You can for instance install Apache with WebDAV on your server. You can find all details on the [SVN Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/). For installation with Apache you can read [this](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html).

Answer (score 1):

you can set the SVn server to be accesable via internet if your computer has an apache server that is accessable via internet.

I asume you are on windows so you might check out :
http://svn.spears.at/

Answer (score 1):

You can visit http://opensvn.csie.org 
I used it several times and it's really good service.